# Powershell - Adding arrays

Tags: powershell

I am trying to list some files in a tree to work on them

```
$files_AppConfig = Get-ChildItem -Path .\App.config -Recurse
$files_WatcherConfig = Get-ChildItem -Path .\WatcherServiceConfig.xml -Recurse
$files_StrControles = Get-ChildItem -Path .\Web.config -Recurse
$files = $files_AppConfig + $files_WatcherConfig + $files_StrControles


ForEach($file in $files)
{   
#Do some stuff
}
```

But when called by visual studio in prebuild event, i have `Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSObject] doesn't contain a method named 'op_Addition'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`+` only does array addition if the first operand (`$files_AppConfig` in this case) is already an array. If `Get-ChildItem -Path .\App.config -Recurse` only returns 1 file, that won't be the case.

You can either force the first operand to be an array by wrapping it in the array subexpression operator `@()`:

```
$files = @($files_AppConfig) + $files_WatcherConfig + $files_StrControles
```

Or, my personal preference, wrap the array subexpression operator around multiple value statements to create one big flat array:

```
$files = @($files_AppConfig;$files_WatcherConfig;$files_StrControles)
```

If you know for certain that the variables contain only scalars, you can also use the `,` array operator:

```
$files = $files_AppConfig,$files_WatcherConfig,$files_StrControles
```